# jquery auto complete style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#staff").autocomplete({
            source: "/classname/methodname",
            minLength: 1,
            typeAhead: true,
            select: function (event, ui) {
            }
        })
            .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, x) {
                return $("<li>")
                  .append("<a>" + x.StaffFullName + " " + x.Department + " </a>")
                  .appendTo(ul);
            };
    });
```

I am using MVC to design my website, I am using autocomplete to find the names of staff who are working in a company. When I run the website I get staff fullname followed by the department. 
I want 3d affect. So i want a black thin line box around the results and when you hoverover a staff name it should be grey colour as the original jquery website have. [Website](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)also the width of my result is too large is there any way I can control it so that according to staff name width will expand.

Comment: apply css style to `ui-menu` and `ui-menu-item` css classes as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can change the width of the auto complete.
Inspect your element and find root div of auto-complete.
search for these classes:
"ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"

```
.ui-widget-content {
border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
color: #222222;
} //for background color.

.ui-menu {
display: none;
left: 561px;
top: 477px;
width: 554px;
}// for div width

.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-br {
border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-focus,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-active {
font-weight: normal;
margin: -1px;
background-color:#CCCCCC !important; 
}/**Color added for autocomplete hover on selected item**/
```

Comment: width is not working, i am getting my result and the background colour is across the page, which is not what i want

Comment: you inspect your result and change the css accordingly.. where you have added your width?? add width to your main ul. for e.g.<ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="display: none; top: 477px; left: 561px; width: 602px;">

Comment: I've used whatever @sanketS said and did .ui-menu{width:150px !important} and it worked.